# Vuescan problems

Tags: drivers, scanner

I am a Ubuntu newbie, trying to get vuescan to work on my Ubuntu system, but with no luck. The software appears to install OK on my Lenovo, and the program opens up fine, but there does not seem to be any connection between PC and scanner. Vuescan works perfectly fine on my iMac and old apple laptop, so the scanner works just fine. 
I've contacted ed Hamrick with details of the Vuescan.log file, after looking at this, he suggested it might be a problem with a missing libsys folder, but my version 16.04 has this installed.
Any suggestions as to what to check next would be welcome.
Thanks, Ken
system details:
Lenovo-G500
Intel® Core™ i3-3110M CPU @ 2.40GHz × 4 
OS type Ubuntu 64 bit Version 16.04
canon scanner 9950
Vuescan version 9 x64  9.5.59 for linux

Comment: Is any of the SANE software installed on your system? Probably required for Vuescan to work.

Comment: Thanks heynnema, I will check to see if the absence of SANE is the problem, Cheers, Ken